# Why not just use HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET Parameter Evaluate method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In the `Evaluate` method of a `Parameter` class (in ASP.NET Web Forms) the `HttpContext` is passed in. Why is this? Is it ever different from the `HttpContext.Current`?